# Websocket performance on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I have issues with websocket performance on AWS EC2.

I use websockets to listen to a server with incoming network rate 100-300 Kb/sec. Just listening, not sending. On EC2, every 10-20 minutes, I get disconnected (code 1006 - abnormal connection loss - no reason given). I have tested with t2.micro (which I believe should be more than enough for such a small task) and t2.large. I use US East, which should be close to the source.

This is to be compared with only one disconnection every few hours when I run the same app on my personal computer, in a different country. I have used two different libraries (Python aiohttp and websockets) to confirm that I have the same issues.

This points to an issue with network quality on EC2. However I'm not sure if this websockets task is demanding, so this is surprising.

Did anyone experience this before? What other diagnostics can I do to better understand the root cause?

Comment: A packet sniffer (e.g. wireshark) on both ends should reveal the problem... on just one end, less helpful but still valuable.  I doubt this is either capacity or quality but rather that the network is tearing down a connection it is concluding has actually already been lost, though why it would conclude this is not clear... but all stateful firewalls (e.g. security groups) will destroy connections they believe to be abandoned because the state tables are of finite capacity.

Comment: I compared t2 and m5 instances types and seems like using m5 solved the problem. m5 have more bandwidth. It is surprising that I have to use these much more expensive machines just for a small websocket app.

Comment: That's unexpected.  I run millions of HTTP(S) requests per day through some of my t2 instances (running HAProxy, which collects several timers for profiling connection performance in both directions) and have never encountered any network-related issues.

Comment: How much CPU does that consume? I'm starting to suspect I went over the t2 CPU credit and therefore ran out of CPU for good networking.

Comment: Ah, yes, if you're depleting your credit balance, that would do it.   HAProxy is written in C and uses epoll, so it's very efficient.  The t2 class has a new feature called T2 Unlimited that removes the credit cap, allowing you to automatically purchase credits for a fee whenever your balance is nearing depletion.  It only costs you when you are using up the standard credit allowance.

Comment: Ok, if HAProxy only takes up a few % of CPU. But an average app (say Python+aiohttp) will take up 50% of a vCPU easily. T2 Unlimited costs 0.05 per hour which is quite high so might as well use an m5 (much higher network bandwidth).

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue, also - code using `websockets` (and also the older `websocket` package) that runs fine on my local machine with long-running, stable connections experiences frequent disconnects when running on EC2 instances